# How to force a pull request (and merge) in git?

Tags: git, pull-request

I completely redesigned an app and now want to merge it with a fork. I do not care for the older version (on my end the old version is already long gone, but I do not care about it on the forked end either - both git accounts are mine as well I should mention). The old version is backed up but isn't going to be needed, ever, so is fine to be overridden.

I would like to make a pull request that completely overrides the old forked version.

I get this message

> othergituser:master and mygithandle:master are entirely different commit histories.

Is it possible to `-f` (force) it somehow?

Comment: Why do you need a pull request at all? Why not force push to master in the original repo?

Comment: @TheGeorgeous good point. I guess a PR was simply more convenient in this case

Comment: Pull requests are provided by web hosting services, not by Git. Therefore, any sort of force option must also be provided by the web hosting service, not by Git. Since you control the fork and can push directly to it, just do the merge yourself, and push directly.